# Remove labels collision in (cytoscape) graph

Tags: angular, layout, cytoscape.js

I am using cytoscape and I am facing one problem: **labels collisions**.

  [Here is an example of collisions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN5nn.png)

I **cannot change text-rotation** parameter (what would solve problem), so I decided to create algorithm to remove this. My first idea was to do this by setting **control point weight** of association, but it is not giving good results (shape of curves, overlapping). My second idea was to change parameters of label position. I found them only in rstyle like **labelX, labelY** (and srcX,tgtX), but when I am changing them curve shape is changing only, not position of label. 

Is there another way to fix it? 

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You control label placement by how you style the graph.  Use the text style properties and the edge properties to make better use of your space or spread things out.  http://js.cytoscape.org/#style

You should only use the public API.

Comment: Thank you! Solution was to change label to source/target-label, thanks to this i could change position.